# syntax error unexpected t_double_arrow yii framework

Tags: php

I,m doing a tutorial application with yii framework. When I tried to run an unit test I got this error in command line

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trackstar/protected/tests/unit/ProjectTest.php on line 11
```

Here is my code. I didn't find the problem in my code . Can anyone help ?

```
class ProjectTest extends CDbTestCase
{
    public function testCRUD()
    {
        //Create a new project
        $newProject=new Project;
        $newProjectName = 'Test Project 1';
        $newProject->setAttributes(
                ￼￼￼￼array(
                'name' => $newProjectName,
                'description' => 'Test project number one',
                'create_time' => '2010-01-01 00:00:00',
                'create_user_id' => 1,
                'update_time' => '2010-01-01 00:00:00',
                'update_user_id' => 1,
                )
                );
                $this->assertTrue($newProject->save(false));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a typo on the keyword `array` or something like that...

Comment: I copy pasted your code and it gave me an error. I think you have some weird character near `array(`

Comment: You have some strange characters just before `array`. Delete the whitespace and recreate it.

Comment: here is nothing to do with yii, it is syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some kind of an unprintable character before your "array" keyword, just delete that one and it will be working

```
class ProjectTest extends CDbTestCase
{
    public function testCRUD()
    {
        //Create a new project
        $newProject=new Project;
        $newProjectName = 'Test Project 1';
        $newProject->setAttributes(
                ￼￼￼array(
                'name' => $newProjectName,
                'description' => 'Test project number one',
                'create_time' => '2010-01-01 00:00:00',
                'create_user_id' => 1,
                'update_time' => '2010-01-01 00:00:00',
                'update_user_id' => 1,
                )
                );
                $this->assertTrue($newProject->save(false));
    }
}
```

You won't see the difference, but it's there